# Float 3 divs around each other

Tags: css

Im a trying to create a css template where 3 text paragrahs interact with each other like this pic:

[image]

It will be repeated over hundreds of pages. All P1 Middle & P2 have differing lengths.

Basically

1) Middle starts a few lines down and is justified
2) each section would fill up the page, but give 1/3 of page to element if it has content.  For example in the pic, where p2 is longer than middle, p2 takes half the page.  And where it is longer than p1, p2 takes up the whole page.

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fVvxb/1/
with a non working image in place of Middle.  It wraps nicely bewlow and to the side, but not over the top margin.

And Im a bit at a loss how to add P2 to the party

Any browser, any js framework would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some additional markup, I think you can achieve your goal assuming:

1. you know (or by javascript can calculate) the height of the MIDDLE, and
2. if possible, keep your longest text in the second *source ordered* `div` (which may end up left or right at your choosing. If #2 is not possible, I'm sure there could be a way to modify the principles here to still make it work, but it would be easiest if the longer text could be always second in the source.

NOTE: at present I only have access to IE8 browser to test.

The fiddles are: left long http://jsfiddle.net/fVvxb/58/ and right long http://jsfiddle.net/fVvxb/59/.

Some further recommendations are to control it by container class. Minified code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapContainer right"> <!-- change class to left for left short column -->
<div id="p1"> <!-- floats the direction of wrapper's right or left class name -->
    <div class="positioner"></div>
    <img src="img.jpg" class="centerImg">
    <div class="padder">
       ...preferably short text always goes in first group... 
       ...if not, modifications to how this works will need to be made... 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="p2">
    <div class="positioner"></div>
    <div class="dummyImg"></div>
    <div class="padder">
       ...long text should always go here for this solution...          
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left #p1 {
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid blue; /* just for show */
    width: 50%; /* width is needed on this, but that limits it to not wrap below middle image, so this is why it should be applied to the shortest text only */
    margin-right: 10px; /* separating the two columns */
}
.left #p1 .centerImg {
    float: right; /* floated oppostie the p1 */
    clear: right; /* this clears the positioner div */
    margin: 0 -100px 0 10px; /* the negative margin is half picture width */
    width: 200px; 
    height: 99px;
 }

/* all the right version css is just a reversal of the left already explained */
.right #p1 {float: right; border: 1px solid blue; width: 50%; margin-left: 10px}
.right #p1 .centerImg {float: left; clear: left; margin: 0 10px 0 -100px; width: 200px; height: 99px;}

#p2 {border:1px solid red;}
.left #p2 .dummyImg { /* this is used to affect the p2 where the img is in p1 */
    float: left; 
    clear: right; /* both positioner divs are floated the opposite direction as the p1 */
    width: 100px; /* half the middle image width */
    height: 99px; /* this is why height of the middle (img) must be known */
    margin: 0 10px 0 -10px; /* this is just offseting and creating margins */
 }

.right #p2 .dummyImg {float: right; clear: left; width: 100px; height: 99px; margin: 0 -10px 0 10px;}

.left .positioner {
    float: right; /* floated oppostie the p1 */
    width: 0; /* this keeps it from interfering with the columns, letting the text flow above the middle image */
    height: 75px; /* this is the offset from the top for the middle image */
}
.right .positioner {float: left; width: 0; height: 75px;}
.padder {padding: 10px; /* give the text some breathing room */}
```

Comment: yes brilliant. Looking through you code i got it all working x the middle column height - till I remembered your point 1!  Now all I have to do is brush on on my JS!  Thanks a lot - a big help.

Answer (score 1):

put P2 at the background and put P1 above P2 and then P3 above P2. So you just have to manipulate zindex of the div.

http://segment7.net/projects/web/z-index.html

Comment: can you be more specific?  No floats, just z index?  What about positioning?  I dont follow your answer..

Comment: zindex specifies which position front to back will your div appear in. Then you need absolute layout to position the divs. I will find an example for you...

Comment: there the text overlaps and hides the content.  I dont see how that helps the wrapping issue?

Comment: You could tile content in the div to overcome that.

Comment: if i tile, would relative not be easier?

Comment: yes you could put a div inside a div and position it with relative. that should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

To this with floats would be a headache. You should use positioning, an extra `<p>` and z-indexes to make this work:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="p2">
      <p>  Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>

    <div id="p1">
        Lorem Ipsum ...

    </div>

        <div id="middle">
            Lorem Ipsum...
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#p1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 95%;
    background-color: #f00;
    z-index: 2;
}

#p2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0f0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#p2 p
{
    margin-left: 53%;
}

#middle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 40%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAvF4/

Comment: Just saw this now - didnt show up in my inbox!  Looks good but it looks to me that the side divs dont wrap around the middle one. The absolute div sits on top and obscures the text of the side divs?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to make one div wrap content in two other divs. You can use elements placed under the middle div in the two others to fake the wrap though :)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/fVvxb/2/

Comment: sorry I dont see any difference?

Comment: that include how to arrange the divs with css with your given positions.

Answer (score 0):

float P1 and P2 and position "middle" absolute over them

Comment: when I use absolute, the divs overlap on top of each other.  If thats the route - how do i wrap the relative divs around the absolute?